# Spring Cloud breaks i18n messages

Tags: internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a spring boot Thymeleaf web application with internationalised messages.
The default translations are in my `messages.properties` file.

My `application.yml` directs the `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration` to these messages:

```
spring:
 messages:
  basename: locale/messages
```

When I run the app, a breakpoint in `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.setBasename()` is hit with the argument `locale/messages`, and everything works beautifully.

Now I want to use Zuul to set use this application as a [reverse proxy](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy) to pass requests through from the browser to a REST application.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ThymeleafApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

So I add some config to my `application.yml`:

```
zuul:
 routes:
  rest-api:
   path: /rest-api/**
   url: https://localhost:443/my-rest-api
```

and my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.0.4.RELEASE'
}
```

The reverse proxy now works correctly, but the internationalisation is broken. Messages are displayed as '??page1.message1_en_GB??'. The breakpoint in `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.setBasename()` is no longer triggered.

**How can I set up Zuul so that my i18n still works?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot MessageSourceAutoConfiguration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663513/spring-boot-messagesourceautoconfiguration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've fixed this by upgrading to the latest version of Spring Boot, 1.3.1.RELEASE.

It was [a bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/29) as pointed out in @nerdherd's answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663513/spring-boot-messagesourceautoconfiguration#answer-31616702).