# Spring boot application and MessageSource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been trying to create a demo spring boot app with MessageSource, but i couldn't figure out what is the problem. I tried in couple of ways:

- MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
- Creating my own bean within a @configuration file and autowiring it

Below is the **MessageSourceAutoConfiguration** way:

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent **1.5.7.RELEASE**.

**My folder structure:**

[image]

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**DemoController.java**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController implements MessageSourceAware
{
  private MessageSource messageSource;

  @Override
  public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource)
  {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
  }

  @RequestMapping("demo")
  public String getLocalisedText()
  {
    return messageSource.getMessage("test", new Object[0], new Locale("el"));
  }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
spring:
  messages:
    basename: messages
```

**messages.properties**

```
test=This is a demo app!
```

**messages_el.properties**

```
test=This is a greek demo app!
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>com.example.i18n.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
    8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**While starting up the server, i can see that the AutoConfiguration works, but cannot find a bean:**

```
MessageSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - ResourceBundle found bundle URL [file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/demo/demo/target/classes/messages.properties] (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

I tried to also explicitly declare my own bean, but didn't work.

While invoking the endpoint i get the following error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException",
    "message": "No message found under code 'test' for locale 'el'.",
    "path": "/demo"
}
```

The closest SO question i found was this one (2 years old) about a bug in spring which was fixed couple of versions ago:
[Spring Boot MessageSourceAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663513/spring-boot-messagesourceautoconfiguration)

Comment: Small detail, you should not have spaces in your messages files, between the '=' and the translated message.

Comment: Where have you put your `messages.properties`. Also you can remove the `spring.messages.basename` property as that is the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was my Eclipse encoding configuration, which I haven't managed to fix yet.

After debugging Spring's code (`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java`) I could see my `key=value` property loaded, but with 3 space characters before each character (e.g. `t   e   s   t   =   T   h   i   s    i   s    a    d   e   m   o    a   p   p   !`).

On another PC the same demo application works fine.

Answer (score 36):

Can you create a messages package in resources and try this Bean implementation in your configuration file:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); //reload messages every 10 seconds
    return messageSource;
}
```

Additionally, I suggest you to use **@Configuration** annotated configuration classes instead of xml files to be adapted perfectly to Spring Boot concept.

Comment: It works now thanks, it was my eclipse the issue.. i do have my bean this way (hate the xmls) :)

Comment: @nicolas Happy that you found the issue :)

Comment: **watch out!** assume you have file `path/to/messages_en.properties` on base name you have to set : `messageSource.setBasename("file:path/to/messages")` **omitting the suffix**  `_en.properties`

Comment: Note that the method (bean) name *must be* `messageSource()`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on springboot app. I have tested one of the below options:

If you prefer to modify `application.properties` file then add this line `spring.messages.basename=messages` where messages is the prefix of the file containing your messages. with this u don't have to setup a `messagesource` bean yourself.

or

i had to give the `MessageResource` bean a name and autowire it using the name given during initialization, otherwise `DelegatingMessageSource` was being injected and it wasn't resolving to any message source.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean                 
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

        SessionLocaleResolver localResolver=new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageResourceSB")
    public MessageSource messageResource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageBundleResrc=new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageBundleResrc.setBasename("msg.message");
        return messageBundleResrc;
    }

}
```

then autowire the bean with the name u expect

```
@RestController
public class Internationalization {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messageResourceSB")
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @GetMapping(path = "/sayHelloIntern")
    public String sayHello(@RequestHeader(name="Accept-Language",required = false) Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("message.greeting", null, locale);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also configure through application.properties

### below i18n.messages points to messages files under classpath folder i18n

spring.messages.basename=i18n.messages

Refer SpringBoot doc [click here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

Comment: `i18n/messages`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the same but I didn't give any base names for my message source files but it worked.

```
@RestController
    public class HelloWorld {
    
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping(path="/hello-world-internationalized")
    public String helloWorldInternationalized(
            //@RequestHeader(name ="Accept-Language", required= false )
            )
          {
        
        //String str= "Hello-World";
        return messageSource.
                getMessage("good.morning.message", null, "Default Hello",
                        LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        //return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Basename is not required if you place the messages file in root of project. It is visible to all files in the project.