# HTML Element not rendering inside Thymeleaf conditional element

Tags: html, thymeleaf

This is the first time I'm using thymeleaf and I'm using Spring to return flash attributes to the login page if a user enters the wrong credentials.
The error message (2 `div`'s) are displayed but the `<span class="closeBtn">` inside is not rendered.

[image: Image of error message]

*Source Code*

```
<div th:if="${message}" class="row">
    <div th:text="${message}" th:class="${'col s8 offset-s2 m6 offset-m3 alert ' + alertClass}">
        <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

There should be an 'x' at the right of the message. I opened the browser inspector and it just doesn't show in the HTML either.

*Browser Inspector Code*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s8 offset-s2 m6 offset-m3 alert error">Incorrect username / password.</div>
    ::after
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `<span class="closebtn">&times;</span>` is getting overridden by `th:text="${message}"`. Solution is to use `th:utext` and add `<span class="closebtn">&times;</span>` along with you error message.

i.e. in properties file define property like `view.error=Incorrect username/password. <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>`
and use it like

```
<div th:text="#{view.error}" th:class="${'col s8 offset-s2 m6 offset-m3 alert ' + alertClass}"></div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I also added [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718209) to my config class and placed `messages.properties` in the root of my resources folder and that fixed it.