# How to use message.properties in Spring Boot in code instead of hardcoded string

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a `message.properties` in my Spring Boot program and it works fine with Thymeleaf in HTML templates. However, I want to use key=value also in Java code. For example, I have:

```java
public static final String PDF_PROGRAM_INFO_FIRST_LINE = "Some text"
```

In `message.properties`, I have:

```
text = Some text
```

How to put key into my string in code to use it value instead of typing string by hand?

I tried:

```java
public static final String PDF_PROGRAM_INFO_FIRST_LINE =("${text}")
```

However, this doesn't work.

Comment: you can find your solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659679/spring-boot-application-and-messagesource

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it in Spring boot without creating extra beans ? In Thymeleaf it works without any extra configuration (only using th:text="#{text}" ) hence i think springboot got my message.properties already in context.