# Not able to access Message Source in Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I am using the Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE where in I am not able to access the configured Message Source.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
 </parent>
```

[image: Folder Structure]

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulWebservicesApplication {

    //......... some code

    //......... some code
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return resolver;
}

 @Bean
 public MessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource ();
    resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return resourceBundleMessageSource;
}
```

[Above approach is from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659679/spring-boot-application-and-messagesource)

Below is the my restcontroller class method:

```
@GetMapping("/hello-world-I18N")
public String helloWorldI18N(@RequestHeader(name="Accept-Language",required = false) Locale locale) {
    return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message",null,locale);
}
```

Get Request from POSTMAN:
[image]

In Debug log auto configuration did not match.

> MessageSourceAutoConfiguration:
>         Did not match:
>               - ResourceBundle did not find bundle with basename messages (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)

I did tried the other way where in the configuration have been detected but the error was same as highlighted.

```
 @Bean
 public MessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ();
    resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return resourceBundleMessageSource;
}
```

[image: Other Approach without message folder]

```
MessageSourceAutoConfiguration:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: current) found beans of type 'org.springframework.context.MessageSource' resourceBundleMessageSource (OnBeanCondition)
  Matched:
     - ResourceBundle found bundle URL [file:/C:/Users/gaura/IdeaProjects/restful-webservices/target/classes/messages.properties] (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)
```

content of messages.properties:
good.morning.message=Good Morning

Does it is the issue with current Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE just like the [other version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663513/spring-boot-messagesourceautoconfiguration)???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-messagesource):

> When an ApplicationContext is loaded, it automatically searches for a MessageSource bean defined in the context. **The bean must have the name messageSource**.

So the `ApplicationContext` expects `MessageSource` bean defined only with the `messageSource` name.

Currently Spring boot's [`MessageSourceAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.html) is inconsistent with this policy: it does not expose `messageSource` bean if it finds a bean with `MessageSource` class.

So solution to your problem is:

Either change method name to `messageSource`:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
```

Or add name to the bean explicitly:

```
@Bean("messageSource")
public MessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource()
```

---

The behaviour in Spring Boot will change in 2.2.x. The `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration` will expose `MessageSource` if it won't find `messageSource` bean by its name rather than class.

See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/15212) pull request. (disclaimer: I'm the author of the PR)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't refer the docs earlier. Thanks this have worked.